# Бан за микроразметку

Tags: seo, поисковая-оптимизация

В вебмастере появилась проблема. Гугл загнал под санкции сайт. Проблема с микроразметкой. Кто уже работал с данной проблемой?

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Я пробовал гадать по вашему снимку с экрана, но без результатов. Возможно вы можете сообщить нам линк вашего веб-сайта и линки проблемных веб-страниц. Такие ошибки надо анализировать с конкретным кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего неправильно использовали микроразметку по типам, или накрутили оценки

---

Используйте микроразметку по назначению:

Желательно в разметке использовать либо Orgaization либо LocalBusines

- product — только для карточек товара. Не нужно ее использовать для категорий товара.
- article — для статей, не для карточек.
- Breadcrumbs не может бать на главной странице.

Не используйте «display: none» в разметке.

Скрытая от пользователей информация нарушает рекомендации Google для веб-мастеров.

> [image]

Проверить микроразметку можно с помощью [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/)

Следите за данными в консоли для веб-мастеров «микроразметка». Появление большого количества ошибок может привести к санкциям.

Источник: https://blog.uamaster.com/google-penalty-letter/